# php code isn't emailing me

Tags: php, html, email

Here is my html form code

I created this and it worked fine with the mailto function, but the problem with it was that it was client side only, and I want it to work server side, so that it sends me the email from the email that they provide.

```
<form action="mailto.php" method="post">
<p>Title:<select>
     <option value="Mr">Mr</option>
     <option value="Mrs">Mrs</option>
     <option value="Miss">Miss</option>
     <option value="Dr">Dr</option>
</select></p>
     <p>First name: <input type="text" name="firstname"></p>
     <p>Last name: <input type="text" name="lastname"></p>
     <p>Steam name: <input type="text" name="steam name"></p>
     <p>Email: <input type="text" name="email"></p>
     <p>What will you bring to this clan? (250 charcater limit)</p>
     <p><textarea name="textbox" id="textbox" textarea maxlength="250"></textarea></p>
     <p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
        <input type="reset" value="Reset"></p>
</form>
```

I haven't had any problems with it until it came to my php code.

Here is my php code

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $to = "someone@hotmail.com"; // this is your Email address
    $from = $_POST['email']; // this is the sender's Email address
    $firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
    $lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
    $subject = "Form submission";
    $message = $firstname . " " . $lastname . " What will you bring to this group?:" . "\n\n" . $_POST['textbox'];

    $headers = "From:" . $from;
    mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
    }
?>
```

please can anyone help me.

Comment: Where is your `$headers` variable?

Comment: @Barmar it's there, the line before.

Comment: I don't know where to put it. Sorry, I am studying this at college so I literally don't know anything about php atm.

Answer (score 1):

***Edit:*** *I originally suggested adding a space after the From: header, however having now re-read the RFC itself, it seems that the space would become part of the value, so I've removed that advice. `"From:{$from}"` is preferable to `"From: {$from}"`.*

--

If you're on a Windows host, you need to provide SMTP connection details in `php.ini` before you can send e-mails with `mail()`. See [`mail()#Notes`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php#refsect1-function.mail-notes).

If you're on Linux, you should have an error message in your PHP error log file. You can find out where this is located by running the following code anywhere on the server and then searching for `error_log` in the output.

```
<?php
phpinfo();
```

Once you know the error that's being generated, I can help more. It may be that the email is being sent successfully and it's being eaten by your spam filter when it reaches the other end.

Comment: What standard says a space is needed after the colon? [RFC 5322](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322.txt) says: _Header fields are lines beginning with a field name, followed by a
   colon (":"), followed by a field body, and terminated by CRLF._ Nothing about a space after the colon.

Comment: Fair enough. I'll modify the line. :)

Comment: Ive done all that and now it says .php was not found on this server.