# HTML/PHP Contact Form wont send to my email but goes to success page

Tags: php, html, forms, email

Hello I'm new to stackoverflow so forgive me if I'm doing anything wrong. Also I have very little knowledge on PHP. So I have this contact form that I want to send to my email when the user submits it. I have been beating my head against the wall for a while now, both files are uploaded to the server, and are in the same directory. The form goes to the success page, but I get no email. help me please.

Also the link to the form is http://xtcracingteam.com/apply.html if that helps.

This is the HTML

```
     <form method="post" action="http://xtcracingteam.com/send_form_email.php">

                    <label class="first-name">
                        First Name
                    </label>
                    <input name="firstName" class="firstName" type="text" placeholder="Joe" required />

                    <label class="last-name">
                        Last Name
                    </label>
                    <input name="lastName" class="lastName" type="text" placeholder="Swanson" required/>

                    <label class="Race-number">
                        Race Number
                    </label>
                    <input name="raceNumber" class="raceNumber" type="text" placeholder="999" required/>

                    <label class="class">
                        Class
                    </label>
                    <input name="bikeClass" class="bikeClass" type="text" placeholder="Mx 450 Production A" required/>

                    <label class="age">
                        Age
                    </label>
                    <input name="personAge" class="personAge" type="text" placeholder="21" required/>

                    <label class="home-town">
                        Home Town
                    </label>
                    <input name="homeTown" class="homeTown" type="text" placeholder="Washougal Washington" required/>

                    <label class="Current-sponsors">
                        Current Sponsors
                    </label>
                    <textarea name="sponsors" placeholder="Gopro, Redbull, Scott..." class="currentSponsors" required></textarea>

                    <label class="recent-achievements">
                        Recent Achievements
                    </label>
                    <textarea name="recentAchievments" placeholder="I won this and that..." class="recentAchievments" required></textarea>

                    <label class="why">
                        Why should we pick you to represent our brand?
                    </label>
                    <textarea name="theWhy" placeholder="(hint: Dont say Cuz im the fastest)" class="theWhy" required></textarea>

                    <label class="email">
                        Email
                    </label>
                    <input name="email" class="email" type="email" placeholder="Example@emails.com" required/>


                    <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Submit!" />
                </form>
```

This is the PHP code

```
    <?php

      if(isset($_POST['email'])) {



// EDIT THE 2 LINES BELOW AS REQUIRED

$email_to = "xtc.racing.team@gmail.com";

$email_subject = "New Application";





function died($error) {

    // your error code can go here

    echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted.        ";

    echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";

    echo $error."<br /><br />";

    echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";

    die();

}



// validation expected data exists

if(!isset($_POST['firstName']) ||

    !isset($_POST['lastName']) ||

    !isset($_POST['raceNumber']) ||

    !isset($_POST['bikeClass']) ||

    !isset($_POST['personAge']) ||

    !isset($_POST['homeTown']) ||

    !isset($_POST['sponsors']) ||

    !isset($_POST['recentAchievments']) ||

    !isset($_POST['theWhy']) ||

    !isset($_POST['email'])) {

     died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you  submitted.');       

}



$first_name = $_POST['first_name']; // required

$last_name = $_POST['last_name']; // required

$email_from = $_POST['email']; // required

$raceNumber = $_POST['raceNumber']; // required

$bikeClass = $_POST['bikeClass']; // required

$personAge = $_POST['personAge']; // required

$homeTown = $_POST['homeTown']; // required

$sponsors = $_POST['sponsors']; // required

$recentAchievments = $_POST['recentAchievments']; // required

$theWhy = $_POST['theWhy']; // required




$email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";



function clean_string($string) {

  $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");

  return str_replace($bad,"",$string);

}



$email_message .= "First Name: ".clean_string($first_name)."\n";

$email_message .= "Last Name: ".clean_string($last_name)."\n";

$email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";

$email_message .= "race number: ".clean_string($raceNumber)."\n";

$email_message .= "bikeClass: ".clean_string($bikeClass)."\n";

$email_message .= "personAge: ".clean_string($personAge)."\n";

$email_message .= "homeTown: ".clean_string($homeTown)."\n";

$email_message .= "sponsors: ".clean_string($sponsors)."\n";

$email_message .= "recentAchievments: ".clean_string($recentAchievments)."\n";

$email_message .= "theWhy: ".clean_string($theWhy)."\n";



// create email headers

$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".

'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .

'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  

?>



<!-- include your own success html here -->



Thank you for contacting us. We will be in touch with you very soon.

 return to <a href="http://xtcracingteam.com">XTCRacingTeam</a>

<?php

}

?>
```

Comment: debug it, start just with `mail()` and hard code the variable

Comment: You're not checking the result of `mail()`, and you're using `@` to suppress error messages. So why wouldn't it go to the success page?

Comment: You're suppressing any error by using `@` before `mail()`. Don't suppress the error and you might find the problem makes itself apparent.

Comment: possible duplicate of [php code isn't emailing me](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22314344/php-code-isnt-emailing-me)

Comment: Alright so I found a few errors once I stopped suppressing them. But even after fixing all of the errors, and removing the @, still no email. How do I check the result of mail()?

Comment: Is this a shared host? Or a virtual server? Is the php mailer configured correctly?

Comment: So good news is I got it to work most of the time, only problem is it completely ignores gmail. if I have it send to a gmail, I get nothing, and if I send it from a gmail, I get nothing. Any ideas?